# javascript .hover function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this piece of code:

```
getOptionText: function(elem, value, config){
    var text = $(elem).innerHTML;
    var configType = this.getConfigValue(config, 'type', false);
    if (!configType) {
        return text;
    }
    switch (config.type) {
        case 'custom_images':
            var image = this.getConfigValue(config, 'images/' + value, false);
            if (image) {
                text = '<img class="mytest" src="' + image + '" alt="' + text +'" />';
                    jQuery(".mytest").hover(function(){
                        jQuery(this).addClass('big-red-box');

                    },function(){
                      jQuery(this).removeClass('big-red-box');});
            }
            break;
```

how I can add the image variable on hover? So all i want is when a customer put the mouse over the small images to display the full image.

Thank you

Edit:

```
    switch (config.type) {
        case 'custom_images':
            var image = this.getConfigValue(config, 'images/' + value, false);
            if (image) {
                text = '<img class="mytest" src="' + image + '" alt="' + text +'" />';
                 $img = $('<img class="mytest" src="' + image + '" alt="' + text + '" />');
                    $img.hover(function () {
                        jQuery(this).addClass('big-red-box');

                    }, function () {
                        jQuery(this).removeClass('big-red-box');
                    });
                jQuery("mytest").append(text);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: add your markup. Also, where is text defined? provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never adding the `img` you create to the DOM. So `jQuery(".mytest")` will never be able to select it. You need to create the `jQuery objec` with your html instead of just having the HTMLs text. To the `jQuery objec` you can bind the `hover` function.

Finally what you are missing is actually adding the element to the DOM.

```
var image = this.getConfigValue(config, 'images/' + value, false);
if (image) {
    $img = $('<img class="mytest" src="' + image + '" alt="' + text + '" />');
    $img.hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('big-red-box');

    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('big-red-box');
    });
    // todo: append $img somewhere in the DOM
}
```

The simplest way to append the `$img` to the DOM would be:

```
$("#parentElementId").append($img);
```

You have a lot of other methods:

- [Insertion inside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)
- [Insertion outside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/)

Comment: thank you Diego, i am not so good in Jquery, can you tell me or give an example how to append img in the dom?

Comment: You have a lot of different ways to append elements to the DOM. Here there are the most common: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: so i can add this $("#parentElementId").append($img); in the  $img.hover(function () {} ?

Comment: You should add it to the DOM outside the `hover` event (before or after binding it, its the same). If you want in the `hover` you could `.show()` it or `.hide()` it.

Comment: can you make this code to fit on my code? i have a lot of errors

Comment: I can't guess your errors and to make my code work all you need is to replace the `parentElementId` with the actual id.

Comment: i do this i will edit add my new code after the first text, maybe you can see where is the issue.

Comment: please take a look now Diego

Comment: You missed the change in the line you assign `text`. The name change wasn't an accident. It's wrapped with `$(...)`

Comment: please take a look now, like this?

Comment: I think it should be jQuery(".mytest").append($img); rather than jQuery("mytest").append(text); (as you typed)

Comment: I wrote `$("#parentElementId")`. If you are going to use a class instead of an id, you should use `$(".parentElementClass")`. However please note that for the `append` you should select the **parent element** in the DOM, not the element itself. And it is in fact the element itself the one that has `mytest` class.

Comment: can you edit your code to work? to be in the same syntax like mine? thank you

Comment: I don't know your markup. I can't just make up where to append the image. In my code all you need to do is replace the line `// todo...` with the `append line` and in the `append line` change `parentElementId`

Comment: i understand but the variable in your code is $img and in code is text? i think there is problem? If i change text variable with $img everything will go crazy there in my code

Comment: The just change my `$img` with any name you like. Even `text` is an option, although it is not representative

Comment: sorry but i don;t understand how, can you take a look here, this is the entire function, can you tell me what I need to replace or what i need to modify? http://en.textsave.org/uFNb

Comment: for example in this moment i have this :  TypeError: $img.hover is not a function

Comment: I can't see why you are getting that error. Please elaborate using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: sorry i can't create a jsfiddle because there is an entire structure in magento. is not a simple javascript file, for this i tell you  that we can;t change the variables and anything there.

Comment: please tell me something $img it is different from text? or can be the same variable? i mean is ok to rename $img with text?

Comment: @RobertD, the assigned value is different. using one name or another is the same.